# How to stop the insider preview builds completely on my phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-930

I have a Lumia 930 running on slow ring Insider Preview. I wish to quit the program now but the only option under Settings->Windows Insider Programme is to put the builds on hold for a maximum of five days. I want to leave the program completely. How do I go about doing that? (there is link to stop getting insider builds completely when you tap on Stop Insider Preview builds button, but it takes me to the help page for the PC version.. which is pretty useless.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this moment the only way to completely exit the Windows Insider Preview is to reinstall the phone using the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-device-recovery-tool-faq).

You can prevent new builds from being installed for up to 5 days though by doing this:

- go to settings -> Update & security
- Windows Insider Programme
- Click "Stop Insider Preview builds"
- Select number of days you want to delay the updates

You'll also see "[Need to stop getting Insider builds completely?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10584/windows-10-stop-receiving-insider-builds)" link to a Microsoft Support which is currently only relevant for the Windows Insider builds on desktop PCs.

Comment: Nice... this works :). Wonder why Microsoft would do this. I will award bounty in 12 hours

Comment: thanks. I assume they want to prevent people from staying on unstable builds. But I agree, there should be an easier way.

Comment: Totally agree WDRT is such a mess, takes too long, requires too much and is not straightforward to the latest W10m version... it's a very very annoying tool, needing for a total revamp

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall Windows insider app
So there is no way any updates will come to your mobile. I've done it before it helped me

Comment: Windows insider app is a legacy item. Uninstalling it now will not stop updates from being delivered. I have no doubt that it has worked for you before. It's just it will not work now.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps,

1. Go to insider app on your phone
2. Click on **...**
3. Select "leave program"
4. Click Continue.

**Reference :** [Stop getting insider build - Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/stop-getting-insider-build-windows-10-mobile)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work anymore. This used to be the way to do it, but now they moved everything to Settings. This option is no longer available.